# Must + present perfect in a narration about past events

Tags: past-tense, narration

As far as I understand, the construction *must + present perfect* is used to make presumptions about past events with the connection to the present:

> Look, somebody must've been here - the stove is still warm.

But what about narration which is put in past simple? Can I use the same construction like this:

> When I woke up and cast a glance on the ceiling, it must have been the
>   early morning.

Is it correct?

Comment: Must + infinitive perfect is used for assumptions about the past with a high probability.

Comment: @rogermue But can it be used in this context, that is in past time narration?

Comment: If you use direct speech in your narration I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across this with a language student; they had just covered the rule that you cannot use "must" in the past, then we came across "I must have forgotten to water the plants". I had to find an explanation to this dilemma and it highlights the importance of teaching in context.

- "Must" in case one is used for obligation: "I must wear a uniform" and you cannot construct the sentence with the past simple, here you would substitute "must" for "had to"
- "Must" in case two is used to express a presumption about the past and uses the present perfect and conveys a past action that relates to the present or a later past event in narratives.

Answer (score -1):

> When I woke up and cast a glance at the ceiling, it must have been the early morning

is not working for me.  How about something like this instead:

> I woke up and cast a glance at the ceiling.  Judging from the pattern of light and shadow, I thought it must still be early, probably around 6 or 6:30.

Comment: So, you have just taken her simple and clear sentence and over complicated it.  Is there a word for a person who edits in the opposite direction by making things less clear?